# Applications of Finite Projective Planes

Tags: projective-geometry

Can someone point me towards some applications of finite projective planes that are approachable without too much background knowledge? So far, I have vector spaces, Latin Squares, and Sudoku, but I was wondering if there were any others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finite projective planes are a special kind of block design:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design
Block designs, and in particular finite projective planes, can be used in the part of statistics which deals with design of experiments.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I was thinking of as well. I'll take a look into that.

Comment: Also, is there a way to relate projective planes to the game Set? I can't quite seem to get it to work, since I can's construct a projective plane from lines and planes in a 3D vector space, since lines and planes have to pass through the origin, while sets don't have to contain any particular card.